# [UIImage circleBrushTexture]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a426a50

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using bridging header to do use the JotUI framework, but I gots a problem.

I get the error from my title question and the culprit is within this function:

```
- (JotSharedBrushTexture*)brushTexture {
    JotGLContext* currContext = (JotGLContext*)[JotGLContext currentContext];
    if (!currContext) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"NilGLContextException" reason:@"Cannot bind texture to nil gl context" userInfo:nil];
    }
    if (![currContext isKindOfClass:[JotGLContext class]]) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"JotGLContextException" reason:@"Current GL Context must be JotGLContext" userInfo:nil];
    }
    JotSharedBrushTexture* texture = [currContext.contextProperties objectForKey:@"brushTexture"];
    if (!texture) {
        // PROBLEM
        NSLog(@"Creating a texture");
        texture = [[JotSharedBrushTexture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage circleBrushTexture]];
        NSLog(@"After creating texture"); // doesn't log from here.
        [currContext.contextProperties setObject:texture forKey:@"brushTexture"];
    }
    return texture;
}
```

and the function being called:

```
+ (UIImage*)circleBrushTexture {
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
    if (!circleBrush) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64, 64));
        CGContextRef defBrushTextureContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        UIGraphicsPushContext(defBrushTextureContext);

        size_t num_locations = 3;
        CGFloat locations[3] = {0.0, 0.2, 1.0};
        CGFloat components[12] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
        CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

        CGPoint myCentrePoint = CGPointMake(32, 32);
        float myRadius = 30;

        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, myCentrePoint,
                                    0, myCentrePoint, myRadius,
                                    kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

        CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);

        UIGraphicsPopContext();

        circleBrush = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    return circleBrush;
}
```

Not sure why this is happening. I tried deleting and reputting the .m file in compile sources, clean project, and compiling the framework but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, if for file with **circleBrushTexture** method selected target is correct (for *.m file)

Comment: would this be in compiled sources, because i do see it there

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you asking about

Comment: When you select source from left side, at the right side you can see list of targets with checkbokses

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean. It only shows the suitcase (pretty much a framework, which I imported)

Comment: Yes sir. It's JotUI: https://github.com/adamwulf/JotUI. I put this project in a workspace. Not sure if this affected it.

Comment: Why don't you just include sources from JotUI? Could you attach screenshot with your source tree?